# MVC3 @HTMLEditFor with DatePicker How to format with ShortDate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following CSHtml in my view
I also have in my model the following code

```
            <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Required_From)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Required_From)
        </td>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
               //debugger
           $("#Required_From").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", changeYear: true,      changeMonth: true });
            });
            $(function () {
               //debugger
                $("#Required_To").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", changeYear: true, changeMonth: true });
            });
    </script>
```

In my Model I have the following code:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Required_To", DbType="DateTime NOT NULL")]
    public System.DateTime Required_To
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Required_To;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Required_To != value))
            {
                this._Required_To = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to be able to show a short date format but when I do I get the following error:
**"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."**
Is there a way to use the model and the datepicker with the short date format?
TIA
Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you always using view models in your views and never pass your domain models to them. So in your view model you could decorate the property with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute, like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime RequiredFrom { get; set; }
}
```

and then since your view will be strongly typed to the view model when you write:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequiredFrom)
```

you will get the desired format.

This being said if you want to go against good practices and not use view models, you could always try this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Required_From", Model.Required_From.ToShortDateString())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the strongly typed views were what I am using. The DisplayFormat would work without rightclicking and applying the using System.ComponentModel but with that small hiccup it was what I was looking for.